# Maintaining jquery.min.js files in Rails assets path

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, include, assets

I have a Rails application built in `Rails 3.0.3` and `Ruby 1.8.7`. Now I am upgrading the same to `Rails 3.1.3` and `Ruby 2.0.0-p247`. While configuring the assets, I have used `jquery-rails` gem inside the Gemfile to include the jquery files. Then I could see that the files `jquery.js` and `jquery.min.js` are installed and served through asset pipeline. The version of jquery library is `jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2`

The problem is that I had several versions of jquery.min.js in my Rails 3.0.3 application like `jquery-1.4.2.min.js`, `jquery-1.4.4.js`, `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`. Whether I need to maintain these files if I am having the updated one in my app (jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2) ?

Hope someone can help me out :)-

Comment: How can you have multiple jQuery versions in a single app? They would be conflicting with each other!

Comment: Will all the functionalities that are working with a previous version perfectly work with Jquery 1.10.2?

Comment: You don't understand what I wrote? If you include five different versions of jQuery it's not like you have all of them, you only have (most probably) THE LAST ONE INCLUDED

Answer (score 0):

If you use asset pipeline then you should probably check your manifest file and see which jquery file is really included.

If you have there something like

```
//= require jquery
```

But there is no file jquery.js in your folders, it means the file is provided by `jquery-rails` gem. You can then safely remove all other jquery files.

See [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails#rails-31-or-greater-with-asset-pipeline-enabled) gem.

Comment: I have used jquery-rails gem and included the jquery files in the manifest.

Comment: That means you can safely remove the others.